# OpenStack4j Core on Karaf ConnectorNotFoundException

Tags: osgi, openstack, apache-karaf, connector, openstack4j

I have an OSGi (Karaf 4.2.1) application that uses OpenStack4j 3.10. To connect the application to OpenStack, I want to use the openstack4j-httpclient. For authentication, I use credentials as follows:

```
os = OSFactory.builderV3()
        .endpoint(ostackServiceConfiguration.getServerAddress())
        .credentials(ostackServiceConfiguration.getUserName(), ostackServiceConfiguration.getPassword(), Identifier.byName(ostackServiceConfiguration.getUserDomainName()))
        .scopeToProject(Identifier.byName(ostackServiceConfiguration.getProjectName()), Identifier.byName(ostackServiceConfiguration.getUserDomainName()))
        .authenticate();
```

When calling "authenticate()", I receive a ConnectorNotFoundException and cannot explain it. The connector is definitely installed in Karaf. Do you have any ideas what could be causing this?

I have reinstalled the packages several times and also restarted Karaf, but unfortunately, it didn't help. All other bundles are functioning without any limitations, so I don't believe it's an issue with Karaf itself.

For debugging purposes, I have examined the code of OpenStack4j, and the error occurs when the program attempting to call the method HttpExecutorService::execute(). This method is only available as an interface in the Core project and is implemented by openstack4j-httpclient. However, it seems that this implementation cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

So for any reasons, the only way to get rid of the problem was, to use a newer version of karaf -.-